# YouTube downloader for Windows

Tags: windows, download-manager, youtube

I would like to have a free (not necessarily) YouTube downloader for Windows (not a website) And I would like to have it adfree too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[3D Youtube Downloader](https://yd.3dyd.com/) is a windows desktop portable application that can download videos from youtube in various quality settings.

It can also convert into multiple formats including audio only for music.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try [youtube-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) - a fork of youtube-dl with additional features and fixes.

Answer (score 3):

**[JDownloader](https://jdownloader.org)** (Freeware)

> JDownloader is a free, open-source download management tool with a huge community that makes downloading as easy and fast as it should be. Users can start, stop or pause downloads, set bandwith limitations, auto-extract archives and much more. It's an easy-to-extend framework that can save hours of your valuable time every day!

Cross-platform, Mac/Win/nix. Can download pretty much anything you ask it to. Can collect links from your clipboard too, so you don't have to specifically copy/paste to it.
For Youtube, it can download all the individual components that make up the post, not just the video - it can separate out the audio, poster frame, subtitles etc if you want it to.

It's not 100% ad-free, but they take up a teeny bit of the top right menu bar you can totally ignore them & are generally for download sites/structures the app itself enables you to use & save credentials for. I wouldn't really count that against it.